# What's wrong with my "contains" algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry

Modeling closely to Java AWT's [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) class, I have my `Rectangle` POJO:

```
public class Rectangle {
    // The Coordinate of the upper-left corner of the Rectangle.
    private Coordinate upperLeft;   // upperLeft.getXVal() and upperLeft.getYVal()

    // The width of the Rectangle.
    private BigDecimal width;

    // The height of the Rectangle.
    private BigDecimal height;

    // Determine if we wholly contains otherRectangle. (no touching sides).
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Rectangle otherRectangle) {
        BigDecimal x = otherRectangle.getUpperLeft().getXVal();
        BigDecimal y = otherRectangle.getUpperLeft().getYVal();
        BigDecimal w = otherRectangle.getWidth();
        BigDecimal h = otherRectangle.getHeight();
        BigDecimal x0 = getUpperLeft().getXVal();
        BigDecimal y0 = getUpperLeft().getYVal();

        if(isSingularity() || w.doubleValue() <= 0.0 || h.doubleValue() <= 0.0)
            return false;

        return (
            x.doubleValue() >= x0.doubleValue() &&
            y.doubleValue() >= y0.doubleValue() &&
            (x.doubleValue() + w.doubleValue()) <= (x0.doubleValue() + getWidth().doubleValue()) &&
            (y.doubleValue() + h.doubleValue()) <= (y0.doubleValue() + getHeight().doubleValue())
        );
    }
}
```

When I execute the following code:

```
// r1 has upperLeft corner at (0,4), width = 6, height = 4
// r2 has upperLeft corner at (1,2), width = 1, height = 1
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(new Coordinate(0,4), 6, 4);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(new Coordinate(1,2), 1, 1);

boolean result = r1.contains(r2);
```

The answer is false!

Note, I wrote this with the following assumption:

- The `upperLeft` coordinate field is just that - the rectangle's upper-left corner; this implies:
- that the pseudo-code for obtaining the upper-right's coordinate is `(upperLeft.x + width, upperLeft.y)`
- that the pseudo-code for obtaining the lower-left's coordinate is `(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y - height)`
- that the pseudo-code for obtaining the lower-right's coordinate is `(upperLeft.x + width, upperLeft.y - height)`

Now then, I believe there's something awry about my return value:

```
    return (
        x.doubleValue() >= x0.doubleValue() &&
        y.doubleValue() >= y0.doubleValue() &&
        (x.doubleValue() + w.doubleValue()) <= (x0.doubleValue() + getWidth().doubleValue()) &&
        (y.doubleValue() + h.doubleValue()) <= (y0.doubleValue() + getHeight().doubleValue())
    );
```

But I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Try splitting up that return statement in multiple values to see which one is wrong.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It shows a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), is original, tractable and is clearly a programming problem.

Comment: @TicketMonster I've added a graph to help with the understanding, please check to see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `y` inequalities mixed up. Because you use top-left as the starting point you need to check for containment in the negative direction.

[image]

The above image plots `r1` (green) and `r2` (pink). To fix your code make the following adjustments

```
// y must be less than y0
y.doubleValue() <= y0.doubleValue()

// y - h must be greater than y0 - h0
(y.doubleValue() - h.doubleValue()) >= (y0.doubleValue() - getHeight().doubleValue())
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing two different coordinate systems. Your code uses the coordinate system where the Y axis points from top to bottom (this is often used in computer graphics). At the same time your comments refer to the standard mathematical coordinate system where the Y axis points from bottom to top.

This is why your code doesn't work the way you expect it to.

You need to decide which coordinate system to use, and then either fix the code or change the way you compute coordinates in your head.

Comment: How so @NPE? If the **upper left** corner of r1 is (0,4), then you must add the width and subtract the height to get the other coords. That means its 3 other coords will be (0,0), (6,0) and (6,4). And if you do the same for r2, then its coords are (1,1), (1,2), (2,2) and (2,1)...

Comment: @TicketMonster If the upper left is (0, 4), why are you subtracting the height the get the other coordinates?

Comment: In a normal mathematical context I would agree, but in Java-2D-Context the origin is in the top-left corner, so the y-axis is inverted and r1 does not contain r2.

Comment: I'm so confused everyone! If **upper left corner is (0,4)** then it represents both the top-most (y-axis wise) and left-most (x-axis wise) coordinate on the rectangle. So you add width to get upper-right and lower-right x-values, and you subtract the height to get lower-left and lower-right y-values. Since it's the upper corner, it's saying "**Nothing in the rectangle is left of me, and nothing in the rectangle is taller than me**".

Comment: @TicketMonster: You are confusing two different coordinate systems. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again @NPE - take look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) - is this not a standard Cartesian coordinate system? What am I missing here?

Comment: @TicketMonster: It is, but that's not what your code uses (why are you adding the height to the top coordinate instead of subtracting it?)

Comment: The problem is clearly my "algorithm" (everything in the return statement) - and that is the basis of my question: "**What's wrong with my contains algorithm?**" I'm telling you, I wrote this with the intention to use a traditional (x,y) Cartesian plane (like the one I linked to above). So the answer to my question would be helping me figure out how to tweak my algorithm to work on a normal Cartesian plane (since I clearly botched something)...

Comment: @TicketMonster: I think the answer (and the comments) give you all the information you need to fix the algorithm (and your understanding).